# ewm_mean ignore nan

Tags: python, dataframe, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

Given a series with possible `NaN` values, how does one tell polars to ignore the `NaN` values? That is, treat the `NaN` value as if it weren't in the DataFrame, and use the same value for the mean as in the cell before the `NaN` value.

To be 100% specific, this is the default behavior for panda's class of functions [ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) and [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the `fill_nan` method.  There is currently a [request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3066) to expand the `fill_nan` method to have the same handy options as the [`fill_null`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html) method (i.e., 'forward', 'backward', 'mean', etc..).

But we can get the same results with a slight workaround. Let's suppose our data looks like this:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": (["a"] * 3) + (["b"] * 4),
        "obs": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "val": [1.0, np.NaN, 3, 4, np.NaN, np.NaN, 7],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ obs ┆ val │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ a     ┆ 1   ┆ 1.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2   ┆ NaN │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 3   ┆ 3.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 1   ┆ 4.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2   ┆ NaN │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 3   ┆ NaN │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 4   ┆ 7.0 │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘
```

As long as your column does not have `null` values, we can convert the `NaN` values to `null` and then use the `fill_null` expression.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(pl.col("val").fill_nan(None).keep_name())
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("val").fill_null("forward").over("group").alias("fill_forward"),
            pl.col("val").fill_null("backward").over("group").alias("fill_back"),
            pl.col("val").fill_null("mean").over("group").alias("fill_mean"),
            pl.col("val").fill_null("zero").over("group").alias("fill_zero"),
            pl.col("val").fill_null("one").over("group").alias("fill_one"),
        ]
    )
)
```

```
shape: (7, 8)
┌───────┬─────┬──────┬──────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ group ┆ obs ┆ val  ┆ fill_forward ┆ fill_back ┆ fill_mean ┆ fill_zero ┆ fill_one │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64          ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64      │
╞═══════╪═════╪══════╪══════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ a     ┆ 1   ┆ 1.0  ┆ 1.0          ┆ 1.0       ┆ 1.0       ┆ 1.0       ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2   ┆ null ┆ 1.0          ┆ 3.0       ┆ 2.0       ┆ 0.0       ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 3   ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0          ┆ 3.0       ┆ 3.0       ┆ 3.0       ┆ 3.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 1   ┆ 4.0  ┆ 4.0          ┆ 4.0       ┆ 4.0       ┆ 4.0       ┆ 4.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2   ┆ null ┆ 4.0          ┆ 7.0       ┆ 5.5       ┆ 0.0       ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 3   ┆ null ┆ 4.0          ┆ 7.0       ┆ 5.5       ┆ 0.0       ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 4   ┆ 7.0  ┆ 7.0          ┆ 7.0       ┆ 7.0       ┆ 7.0       ┆ 7.0      │
```

You can also use other methods with `null` values as well, such as `interpolate`.

```py
(df
 .with_column(pl.col("val").fill_nan(None).keep_name())
 .with_column(pl.col("val").interpolate().over("group").alias("inter"))
)
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ obs ┆ val  ┆ inter │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1   ┆ 1.0  ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2   ┆ null ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 3   ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 1   ┆ 4.0  ┆ 4.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2   ┆ null ┆ 5.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 3   ┆ null ┆ 6.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 4   ┆ 7.0  ┆ 7.0   │
└───────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```